# Extjs4 - Form submit always returns a failure

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs, extjs4

I'm submitting an excel file using an `ExtJS 4` form but even when the request is successful it registers a failure. What is the `form.submit` function expecting to see?

[image: Console]

**Form**

```
xtype: 'form',
name: 'upload_form',
items: [{
      text: 'File Upload',
      xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
      name: 'upload_btn',
      buttonOnly: true,
      hideLabel: true,
      allowBlank: false,
      clearOnSubmit: false
}]
```

**Controller**

```
'filter fileuploadfield[name="upload_btn"]': {
            change: this.UploadClick
        }
    ...
    UploadClick: function (vb, s) {
    var controller = this,
        form = controller.getUploadForm();

    if (form.isValid()) {
        form.submit({
            url: '/upload',
            waitMsg: 'Uploading your csv...',
            success: function (fp, o) {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title: 'Upload Complete',
                    msg: o.response.responseText,
                    icon: 'save-success',
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            },
            failure: function (fp, o) {
                Ext.Msg.show({
                    title: 'Upload Error',
                    msg: o.response.responseText,
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Java return**

```
Response.ResponseBuilder builder;
...
builder = Response.ok(null);
        return builder.build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't send a `null` [Response](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.ResponseBuilder.html) ...but the expected `JSON` along with a proper content-type header:

```
String json = "{\"success\": true}";
return Response.ok(json, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach parameter `success` in response:

E.g:

```
{
    "success":true, // note this is Boolean, not string
    "msg":"File uploaded"
}
```

As in the documentation: 
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit

Answer (score 0):

In my case ( Spring Boot application with Ext JS 6.2), if you are returning a list of objects, you can use a wrapper. For example,

Instead of doing:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<List<User>> getUsers() {
    List<User> users = repository.getAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Do this:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Users> getUsers()
{
    List<User> users = repository.getAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new Users(users, true), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

where Users class is:

```
public class Users
{
   private List<User> users;
   private boolean success = true;
   public Users(List<User> users, boolean success)
   {
      this.users = users;
      this.success = success;
   }

   public List<User> getUser()
   {
      return users;
   }

   public void setUser(List<User> users)
   {
      this.users = users;
   }

   public boolean isSuccess()
   {
      return success;
   }

   public void setSuccess(boolean success)
   {
      this.success = success;
   }
}
```